# cloudbees git push fails with error 504

Tags: git, cloudbees, playframework-2.3

I am try to apply my changes on code to my cloudbees account using

```
git push origin master
```

but after few minutes action fails with following error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.cloudbees.com/username/reponame.git/': The requested URL returned error: 504
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of problem is Cloudbees internal server error. my problem resolved after 5 hours. Try it later!